# Problem displaying html with bootstrap-table.js

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap-table

I have created a dynamic list with a bootstrap filter, but there is a problem displaying all the links.

I do not know why the HTML code is displayed

Please help me please.

cordially.

[image]

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin/master/tableExport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" />
```

```html
<table id="table" 
    data-toggle="table"
    data-search="true"
    data-filter-control="true" 
    data-show-export="true"
    data-click-to-select="true"
    data-toolbar="#toolbar">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
   <th data-field="article" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Article</th>
            <th data-field="composant" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Composant</th>
            <th data-field="fournisseur" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Fournisseur</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <? while($row = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  ?>           
  <tr>
   <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
   <td><a href="#"><?php echo $row['code_article'] ?></a></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['comp'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['fournisseur'] ?></td>
  </tr>
    <? } ?> 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide debug information and add a ```var_dump($row['code_article']);``` in your while loop, so we are able to see the raw data output

Comment: the problem is not on the $ row ['code_article'], it's recovering
I think bootstrap that makes this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `data-escape="false"` to your table tag - then the "plain" HTML will be rendered

```
<table id="table" 
    ...
    data-escape="false"
>
```

see https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#escape

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much

with attribute data-escape="false" it works perfectly.